# Convergence of the positive operator $ \big( A+ (\lambda)^n B\big)^{\frac{1}{n}},$ where $0< \lambda <1.$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, soft-question, monotone-functions

Let $A, B$ be two positive operators in $M_{n}(\mathbb{C}).$ We know that $\lim_{n\to \infty}A^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges and $\lim_{n\to \infty}A^{\frac{1}{n}}= P_{\rm ran(A)},$
where $P_{\rm ran(A)}$ denote the projection into range of $A.$
I am interested to know the limit of the sequence
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \big( A+ (\lambda)^n B\big)^{\frac{1}{n}},$$
where $0< \lambda <1.$
Some simple case, we can conclude that the above limit exists. However, I do not know in full generality.
Any suggestions and input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define $(A)^\frac{1}{n}$ for a non-self-ajoint operator $A$? Or does positive include self-ajoint?

Comment: @ Meowdog:  every positive operator is a self-adjoint operator.

Comment: If $A\neq 0$ and if $A+ \lambda^{\frac{1}{n}} B$ has no zero eigenvalue, then you can just write $(A+ (\lambda)^n B)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \exp(n^{-1}\log(A+(\lambda)^{\frac{1}{n}}B))$ and compute that limit. Then you immediately see that the result is the identity matrix. $A=0$ is of course also easy. But the case where $A \neq 0$ and $A+ \lambda^{\frac{1}{n}} B$ has vanishing eigenvalues should be ugly... Have you done some numerical experiments?

Comment: Apparently the limit is $\Pi_{\operatorname{range}(A)}+\lambda\Pi_{\operatorname{range}(B)\cap\ker(A)}$, where $\Pi_S$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto a linear subspace $S$.

Comment: @user1551 Interesting.... Looks plausible at first sight. How did you intuitively get there?

Comment: @user1551: It seems very interesting, Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: The problem statement seems to have overloaded $n$... perhaps you mean operators in $M_{r}(\mathbb{C})$

Answer (score 3):

The limit exists and is equal to $\Pi_{\operatorname{range}(A)}+\lambda\Pi_{\operatorname{range}(B)\cap\ker(A)}$, where $\Pi_S$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto a linear subspace $S$.

The result is clear if $A=0$ or $B=0$. Let us assume that $A,B\ne0$. Since convergence of the sequence and the limit value are invariant under scaling of $A$ and $B$ by a common positive factor, we may further assume that $\|A+B\|_2\le1$.

Let $u$ be an arbitrary unit vector in $\operatorname{range}(A)$. Then
$$
u^\ast A^{1/n}u
\le u^\ast(A+\lambda^nB)^{1/n}u
\le u^\ast(A+B)^{1/n}u
\le \|(A+B)^{1/n}\|_2
\le 1.
$$
Pass $n$ to the limit, we obtain
$$
1=u^\ast u=u^\ast\Pi_{\operatorname{range}(A)}u
\le \lim_{n\to\infty}u^\ast(A+\lambda^nB)^{1/n}u
\le 1.
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}u^\ast(A+\lambda^nB)^{1/n}u=1\tag{1}
$$
or equivalently, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle u,u_n\rangle=1$ where $u_n=(A+\lambda^nB)^{1/n}u$. Since $\|u_n\|_2\le\|(A+\lambda^nB)^{1/n}\|_2\le\|(A+B)^{1/n}\|_2\le1$, we must have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=u.\tag{1a}
$$

Now let $v$ be an arbitrary unit vector in $\operatorname{range}(B)\cap\ker(A)$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}v^\ast(A+\lambda^nB)^{1/n}u=v^\ast \lim_{n\to\infty}v^\ast u_n=v^\ast u=0.\tag{2}
$$
Furthermore, for any fixed $n$, if $A+\lambda^n B=USU^\ast$ is a unitary diagonalisation and we put $p=U^\ast v$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lambda v^\ast B^{1/n}v
&\le v^\ast(A+\lambda^n B)^{1/n}v\\
&=p^\ast S^{1/n}p\\
&=\sum_i|p_i|^2s_i^{1/n} \quad\text{(which is a convex combination of the $s_i^{1/n}$s)}\\
&\le(\sum_i|p_i|^2s_i)^{1/n} \quad\text{(because $x\to x^{1/n}$ is concave on $\mathbb R_{\ge0}$)}\\
&=(p^\ast Sp)^{1/n}\\
&=\left(v^\ast(A+\lambda^n B)v\right)^{1/n}\\
&=\lambda(v^\ast Bv)^{1/n} \quad\text{(because $Av=0$)}\\
&\le\lambda\|B\|_2^{1/n}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Pass $n$ to the limit, we obtain
$\lambda=\lambda v^\ast \Pi_{\operatorname{range}(B)}v
\le \lim_{n\to\infty}v^\ast(A+\lambda^n B)^{1/n}v
\le \lambda$. Therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}v^\ast(A+\lambda^n B)^{1/n}v=\lambda.\tag{3}
$$
Finally, we also have $\ker(A)\cap\ker(B)\subseteq\ker(A+\lambda^n B)=\ker\left((A+\lambda^n B)^{1/n}\right)$. Therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x^\ast(A+\lambda^n B)^{1/n}w=0\tag{4}
$$
for any $w\in\ker(A)\cap\ker(B)$ and any vector $x$. It follows from $(1)-(4)$ and the polarisation identity that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^\ast(A+\lambda^n B)^{1/n}y$ exists for every pair of vectors $x$ and $y$. Consequently, $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}(A+\lambda^n B)^{1/n}$ exists.

Now let $U=\operatorname{range}(A),\,V=\operatorname{range}(B)\cap\ker(A)$ and $W=\ker(A)\cap\ker(B)$. The whole vector space is then the orthogonal sum of $U,V$ and $W$. By $(1a)$, we have $Lu=u$ for every $u\in U$. Therefore $U$ is an invariant subspace of $L$ and $L|_U=\operatorname{id}$.

By $(2)$ and $(4)$ (with $x\in V$), we also have $LV\perp U$ and $LV\perp W$. Hence $LV\subseteq(U+W)^\perp=V$, i.e., $V$ is an invariant subspace of $L$. By $(3)$, $v^\ast Lv=\lambda$ for every $v\in V$. Hence $L|_V=\lambda\operatorname{id}$.

Now $(4)$ also implies that $LW=0$. Hence $W$ is an invariant subspace of $L$ and $L|_W=0$.

It follows that $L=\Pi_U+\lambda\Pi_V=\Pi_{\operatorname{range}(A)}+\lambda\Pi_{\operatorname{range}(B)\cap\ker(A)}$.

Comment: Although I haven't checked all the details of the answer, I suspect that $L$ actually takes a slightly different form. For example, if $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},\qquad\text{and}\qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&2\\1&2&4\\2&4&8\end{pmatrix},$$then we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(A+\lambda^n B)^{1/n}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}+\frac{\lambda}{5}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&2\\0&2&4\end{pmatrix},$$ but $\operatorname{range}(B)\cap\ker(A)=\{0\}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee In your example, since $\operatorname{range}(B)$ and $\ker(A)$ are two-dimensional, their intersection has dimension $2+2-3=1$. It is spanned by $B(-1,-1,1)^T=(0,1,2)^T$.

Comment: Ah, my bad. It's 3am here and I must be badly sleep-deprived to miss such an easy sanity check. Thank you :)